# Cypress: Error: Getting ESOCKETTIMEDOUT when using cy.visit()

Tags: cypress, cypress-component-test-runner

Brand new project. I am simply trying to access adobe.com but getting a ESOCKETTIMEDOUT error. Given this is a new project, I doubt anything is wrong with the code. I am on MACOS 12.6.1 Monterey with no firewall on. Any settings/changes I need to make?

```
CypressError
cy.visit() failed trying to load:

https://www.adobe.com/

We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.

We received this error at the network level:

> Error: ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Common situations why this would fail:
- you don't have internet access
- you forgot to run / boot your web server
- your web server isn't accessible
- you have weird network configuration settings on your computer
cypress/e2e/spec.cy.js:3:8
  1 | describe('empty spec', () => {
  2 |   it('passes', () => {
> 3 |     cy.visit('https://www.adobe.com')
    |        ^
  4 |   })
  5 | })
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cypress, cy.visit() failed trying to load ESOCKETTIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975352/cypress-cy-visit-failed-trying-to-load-esockettimedout)

Answer (score 2):

It was answered here: [Cypress, cy.visit() failed trying to load ESOCKETTIMEDOUT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975352/cypress-cy-visit-failed-trying-to-load-esockettimedout)

Just add the object `{ headers: { "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate" } }` as the second argument of cy.visit (but no need to modify Cypress config file in my case)